# Black drawings showing as white

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency

I'm in the Blender render mode, not Cycles. I created a texture with an alpha channel and drew on it with a black-coloured brush, enabled Z Transparency on the material it was applied to and enabled the Alpha influence in the Influences tab, only to find the black drawing is white (see below).

[image]

I'm not sure why it's doing this. Is it because of the material behind it also being black? I'd like to know how to fix this problem.

Comment: I found a solution but it's not quite what I expected. Go to the material tab and change the Diffuse colour to Black instead of white. This'll make the drawing go black sure but you won't be able to use any colours.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I finally have it. All I had to do was enable the Colour field in the Influence tab via the texture section. It works fine now!